# Laravel scheduling: after hook doesn't get called

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron

My laravel (5.8) app is located on the shared hosting in the folder `app`. Folder bound to the domain is `public_html` located next to `app`. I have a scheduled task like this:

```
$schedule->command('feed:gen sitemap')
             ->withoutOverlapping()
             ->runInBackground()
             ->dailyAt('03:00')
             ->after(function() use($schedule) {
                $schedule->exec('mv ~/app/public/Sitemap.xml ~/public_html/Sitemap.xml');
             });
```

that creates sitemap.xml and moves it to the website root folder. The `command` part works fine, sitemap.xml is created in `~/app/` folder, but `after()` hook doesn't get called. I am pretty sure the paths for `mv` command are fine. On the other hand, it is not clear in the docs how to chain multiple calls including hooks and what function calls are chainable with each other. Maybe I need to chain something else to `$schedule->exec()`?..

PS: `feed:gen sitemap` command is registered in `routes/console.php` like

```
Artisan::command('feed:gen {type}', function (FeedGenerator $gen, $type) {
    // some code
})->describe('Generates feeds for site');
```